# How to change the color for many curves in the same figure in Scilab?

Tags: scilab

I am solving the SIRD model by using Scilab, I am simulating this model for r and b vectors since I put b as a constant value and simulating for r vector by using for loop and I am plotting four outputs (S, I, R, and D) by using subplot command, but I get the four curves in the same colour. How can I use different colours in the same figure? I used plot2d(t, x(1,:),style=[color("red"),color("green"),,color("blue")]) but it does not work. I am going to attach my code and the output figures.
Thanks in advance.

[Figures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tks4P.png)

```
clear
function dxdt=f(t,x)
    S=x(1);
    I=x(2);
    R=x(3);
    D=x(4);
    dxdt=[-alpha*b*S*I
    alpha*b*S*I-(I/r)
    ((1-m)*I)/r
    (m*I)/r]
endfunction
N=10^7;
alpha=10^-6;
m=0.6;
b_vec=[0.05 0.025 0.01];
r_vec=[10 5 3];
t=linspace(0,150,1000);
x0=[10^7-1000;1000;0;0];
// simulation for constant beta b=0.05
clf(0); scf(0);
for i=1:3
    b=0.05; 
r=r_vec(i)
x=ode(x0,0,t,f) 
subplot(2,2,1)
plot(t,x(1,:))

set(gca(),"auto_clear","off")  //hold on
xlabel('time[days]')
ylabel('S')
title ('b=0.05')
legend ('r=10','r=5','r=3')

subplot(2,2,2)
plot(t,x(2,:))
set(gca(),"auto_clear","off")  //hold on
xlabel('time[days]')
ylabel('I')
title ('b=0.05')
legend ('r=10','r=5','r=3')

subplot(2,2,3)
plot(t,x(3,:))
set(gca(),"auto_clear","off")  //hold on
xlabel('time[days]')
ylabel('R')
title ('b=0.05')
legend ('r=10','r=5','r=3')

subplot(2,2,4)
plot(t,x(4,:))
set(gca(),"auto_clear","off")  //hold on
xlabel('time[days]')
ylabel('D')
title ('b=0.05')
legend ('r=10','r=5','r=3')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
colors = ["r" "g" "b"];
```

just before the `for` loop, and

```
plot(t,x(#,:), colors(i))
```

for every plot() command, and that's it.
By the way, all "hold on" rows are useless, since this mode is the default one. And correctly indenting your code makes it always better readable.